# How i can find point that Touching edges of tow circle?

Tags: geometry

i have to circle with Different whidth and radius
so how i can make contact with this tow circle 
and i know the center of each circle.

i have an image to explain what i need:

[image]

so i have the shape1 on the image
and i want to make it like shape 2
what is Formula i should use ?
thanks

Comment: It's hard to see what you mean with a lot of information missing. Could you elaborate?

Comment: what informaion u need?

Comment: It seems that one of the circles is fixed and the other one is to be moved along a fixed line to touch the first one. Do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, you want the two circles to be always tangent to each other.

---

I assumed the centers of the circles lie on some sort of a line, so I'll define them as:
$$f(x):=m x\\
g(x):=n x$$
But the centers can be arbitrarily anywhere. Now the centers must lie on either $\bigl(p,f(p)\bigr)$ or $\bigl(k,g(k)\bigr)$, with $r$ and $t$ as radii respectively. For two circles to meet at exactly one point, draw a line passing through the centers, then we just have to make sure the distance between the centers is equal to the sum of the radii, i.e.:
$$\sqrt{(f(k)-g(p))^2+(p-k)^2}=t+r$$

Solving, for example, for $p$, we find that:
$$\left\{p\to \frac{\sqrt{\left(n^2+1\right) (r+t)^2-k^2 (m-n)^2}+k m n+k}{n^2+1}\right\}\tag{1}$$

This means that given two circles lying on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, with $t,r \in \Bbb R^+$, using $p$ in $(1)$ will always give us two circles tangent to each other for any $k$.

You can check this [Desmos implementation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xarbjfakl6) to see what I mean.